# JSON parse Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, массивы, json, dom

Добрый вечер, хочу разобраться с JSON файлами, создал вот такой JSON в самом файле скрипта и пытаюсь вывести данные с него в `dom` элемент, но мне выдает ошибку `Unexpected token ILLEGAL`, если я же весь массив выставлю в одну строчку без переносов, все видит и выводит указанное значение. 
Что я не так делаю?

```
 var obj = JSON.parse(product);
 document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = obj.tShirts.item1.name;

 var product = '{"tShirts": 
                {"category": "t-shirts", 
                "categoryImg": "url-to-img", 
                "item1": {
                    "name": "Cool t-shirts",
                    "price": "225"
                },
                "item2": {
                    "name": "Red t-shirts",
                    "price": "25"
                }
            },
            "toys": 
                {"category": "toys", 
                "categoryImg": "url-to-img", 
                "item1": {
                    "name": "Car",
                    "price": "22"
                },
                "item2": {
                    "name": "House",
                    "price": "100"
                }
            }
        }';
```

Comment: В конце каждой строки вставьте знак '\', js не понимает многострочный текст в таком виде

Comment: Возможно загружать файл .json локально, что бы избежать данного метода?

Comment: А что мешает сразу объект создавать? Т.е. так `product = {tShirts: {lala: 'lala'}}`, тогда не надо будет парсить и можно хоть как это писать. Если именно строка нужна, то можно создать сначала объект, а потом вызвать `productText = JSON.stringify(product)`

Comment: Ничего не мешает, но хочется именно с данным моментом разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

В JS нельзя простым переводом строки обойтись. Ибо сабж принимает перевод строки за конец инструкции, поэтому `;` не является обязательной.
Почитай [тут](https://www.kobzarev.com/programming/multi-variables-in-javascript.html) возможные методы решения данной проблемы.